# Store and install ruby gems locally for ruby project

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am currently working on sample ruby project (not rails). 
In the rails project we can use [bundle package](http://bundler.io/v1.6/bundle_package.html) command for storing installed ruby gems.

It will lock and cache gems from RubyGems into `./vendor/cache.` folder.

Now I have to use same functionality. So how can I store gems on local machine and when we do `bundle install` it will fetch the required ruby gems from that source.

Answer (score 1):

`bundler` is not part of rails, but it is an independent ruby gem itself. so given you have the `bundle` command available, you can just set up you `Gemfile` and use `bundle install` as you are used to.

This is also described on the [bundler homepage](http://www.bundler.io)

Answer (score 1):

Use Bundler

install bundler from your server prompt (regardless of project folder) to ensure the bundle command is accessible.

```
gem install bundler
```

now that your server has bundler installed make a file under the root of your project called Gemfile and add the source and required gems something similar to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'example_gem'
gem 'example_gem_with_version', ">=0.9.2"
...
```

Now your Gemfile is ready. From the root of your project run the bundle install command and specify your vendor directory

```
bundle install --path vendor
```

After it retrieves the source it will cache it under the vendor directory. To install locally without fetching from rubygems.org simply use

```
bundle install --local
```